# pandas и сохранение результата .str.contains в другой датафрейм

Tags: python, pandas

Необходимо произвести отбор отдельных значений из одного датафрейма по условию, и записать их в другой датафрейм.

Как я это вижу: мы открываем файл *Excel*; из него формируется первый датафрейм. Потом for проходит по нему с определенными условиями, и дальше мы результаты каждого цикла добавляем в второй датафрейм.

Я пытался это сделать так, но это не работает.

```
df = pd.read_excel(fname, index_col=0)
        df2 = pd.DataFrame()
        for teg in r'\bн/о', r'\bакту', r'\bно3', r'\bМОУ':
            df_selected = df[df['Последний комментарий'].str.contains(teg)]
            df2 = df2.append(df_selected)

        print(df2)
```

Comment: если  вы начинаете использовать циклы с фреймом пандас, то скорее всего, вы делаете что-то не так. особенно, если вы делаете это так, как показано в коде. приведите пример исходного фрейма.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из основных преимуществ библиотеки pandas - векторизация операций с табличными данными. Поэтому в общем виде решение вашей задачи, раз вы не предоставили исходных данных, можно привести к одной строке, без всяких циклов:

```
df = pd.read_excel(fname, index_col=0)
df2 = df[df['Последний комментарий'].str.contains('|'.join(tags))]
```

где tags - список с вашими тегами.